# How can I debug why my built-in bluetooth is not working?

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to see bluetooth devices over my computer. I have a Asus x79 Deluxe which supports Bluetooth 4.0. It would be nice if that worked under Linux.

I have installed the following packages:

- `bluez-utils`
- `libopenobex1`

I have `blueman` installed and clicked on "turn bluetooth on". After that, when I click on devices it does not see any. When I click on "Adapters" I get an empty popup.

What is the problem and how can I further investigate it / solve it?

### My System

```
$ uname -a
Linux pc09 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 17 Qiana \n \l

$ lspci | grep -i blu
$ lsusb | grep -i blu
$ lshw | grep -i blu
$ lsmod | grep -i blu
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
$ hciconfig --all


$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.746659] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    3.746667] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.746672] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.746673] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.746675] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.796894] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.796898] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.796904] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.797018] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.797021] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.797024] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

$ sudo hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I am not sure, but I think the WLAN chipset `BCM4352` is also the part that handles bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid BCM4352 is [not supported by current Linux kernel's b43 driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43). I would suggest trying Dell's or Broadcom's proprietary drivers instead, see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432933/linux-ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-broadcom-corp-bcm-4352-wireless-network-adapter) for same problem on an older version of Ubuntu.

If they provide a .deb package for Ubuntu 14, you'll likely be able to see the device with `blueman` and use it.

**NOTE:** it will affect your wifi functionality as well

Comment: I have seen that page. However, I have enabled a proprietary driver and WLAN seems to work. What does the `wl` in the column "alternative" mean?

Comment: And what does "PHY" mean on that page (in the table header row).

Comment: "PHY" is the radio chipset, see also the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY_%28chip%29)

Comment: "wl" is just another wireless driver in Linux, but is not alternative to yours as you can see from that table, there's no point in trying it. You say that you have enabled a proprietary driver, but this is not what I said in the answer. You need to use the one provided by vendor (Dell/Broadcom/Asus...), if there's any available. Your chipset is not yet supported natively. So yes, it will be difficult to make it work.